# android static library usage

Tags: android, static, android-ndk

I have a functionality to achieve, which is a difficult one. But someone else already achieved  it in their app. So i decompiled the apk file to find out what he did.

And i found that he has lib like libs/armabi/XXXX.so

Then in the code, he is loading the the lib like this

```
static
  {
    System.loadLibrary("XXXX");
  }
```

Then he call the native method like

```
  public native int addTwoNumbes(int a, int b);
```

So i copied the lib to my libs/armabi/XXX.so

When i call , System.loadLibrary(XXXX) , no error was thown.

But when i call the addTwoNumbers method, it gives me UnsatisfiedLinkError.

Can anyone point me in the right direction , if its not a huge problem for you a quick fix code really helps me as im in kinda hurry (as everyone :) )

Comment: What is the full name of the native method as it appears in the .so?  See also http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the java class name should be exactly the same name,  same package as frim where you took the code,  for more details read about jni

Comment: thx for the quick reply. im not using any code , all i have is a XXX.so file. an i want to call a method in it. i understood that reading about the JNI will help, but im in kind of hurry, i you can help me about the pocess. i owe u a lot

Comment: i have static/shared library which is a .so file. and i need to call a method in it.